# How to read a PubNub message from arduino

Tags: arduino, pubnub

I'm trying to control an Arduino LED from an Android phone (I already have the code for that and read the `PubNub` android doc about it) but I'm so confused about how to read the message I sent from my android app to the channel. I know the messages arrive well in the Arduino board (with an Ethernet shield) because I get them in logs. 
I'm very new to Arduino so my question is : How do I deal with the message I get?

Example : I would like to do that

```
if (message == "test")
{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
```

My code in the loop :

```
Ethernet.maintain();

PubSubClient *client;


Serial.println("waiting for a message (subscribe)");
client = PubNub.subscribe(channel);
if (!client) {
    Serial.println("subscription error");
    delay(1000);
    return;
}
Serial.print("Received: ");
while (client->wait_for_data()) {
    char c = client->read();
    Serial.print(c);
}
client->stop();
Serial.println();

delay(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the message received by the Arduino in a buffer as shown in github.com/pubnub/arduino#synopsis. Then you can analyze the buffer for a command. IF you are more comfortable with JS, then you might find this post on how you can use [Johnny Five to code on the Arduino](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-05-25-howcreate-a-smart-device-with-arduino-and-node-js-using-johnny-five/) useful.